# How to predict system resource need?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, estimation, prediction

Is there any software or way to predict system resource need by taking several inputs such as MySQL query read/write ratio, queries executed in a second, properties of tables and databases, maybe some more inputs related with PHP configurations etc. ?

Yes. I know there is probably no perfect solution a software can provide me but I'm not looking for a perfect solution.

Comment: Do you have any idea of the scale of your app and the kind of queries that you are going to run on it?

Comment: don't know about prediction, but you can simulate server load with tools like jMeter, and you can use the profiling features of PHP debuggers such as XDebug to build up a picture of how long a PHP script takes to execute (though in my experience the profile itself can add a fair amount of overhead to the running script so while its udeful for code optimizations its usefulness as a performance prediction utility may be limited).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few tools that may come in handy:
AWS Cloudwatch, but will work only with EC2. Setup an alarm, say for CPU utilization, so the moment you exceed, say 75%, an alarm email or sms will be sent to you, so you can look around accordingly.

AWS Elsatic Load Balancer, will help you to further distribute the traffic, releasing the unhealthy instance and routing the traffic to a healthier server.

Some monitoring tools like... missing on the names... but if you can take care of things with a self monitoring way, when we use a control panel like webmin, you can get the details of CPU Usage, RAM usage, storage, etc...

And lastly, just a concept, but will take a lot to complete, and I will follow what algolicious just stated above, create a mathematical model which can work on cron, so every 5 mins the observation can be recorded, and action be taken when required.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a mathematical model to compute a forecast of system resources. I would compute a empirical probability density estimate based on Bayesian statistics. More formally you want to compute something like:

E[Memory|CPU=0.9,QuerySpeed=0.6,...]

You can update the distribution based on new signal events using Bayes theorem:

P(A | B) = P(B | A)P(A)/P(B)

This will adapt to new empirical evidence.

Comment: Thanks but I couldn't understand. Can you simplify it?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using a scaleable platform such as Amazon Web Services.  You can start out with a micro instance and configure load balancing to fire up more instances as needed.

Once you determine average resource requirements you can then resize your image to larger or smaller depending on your needs.

http://aws.amazon.com
http://tuts.pinehead.tv/2011/06/26/creating-an-amazon-ec2-instance-with-linux-lamp-stack/

Answer (score 0):

mysqltuner is a perl based script..

i highly recommend you to try this one...

download mysqltuner from  here

```
http://mysqltuner.pl/mysqltuner.pl
```

its command line application and give you the detail what resources you need for your current application...